# Download file using WebClient (C# Script) in a SSIS package

Tags: c#, ssis

I am trying to download a file (https://www2.optimalblue.com/Metrics/OPTIMAL%20BLUE%20MORTGAGE%20MARKET%20INDICES%20(OBMMI).xlsx) with C# in a SSIS package. It will not work for this file! I've been able to download other files, including xlsx files but when I point at this specific file it just won't work.

I can use the exact same script inside a C# Console app in Visual Studio and it will download the file perfectly. I'd like to have it work in the SSIS C# script task. Please help!

Here's the C# I'm using:

```
using (var client = new WebClient()) { 
    client.DownloadFile("https://www2.optimalblue.com/Metrics/OPTIMAL%20BLUE%20MORTGAGE%20MARKET%20INDICES%20(OBMMI).xlsx", 
    @"c:\files\ObFile.xlsx");
 }
```

And here's the error message its giving me in SSIS when I run the script task:

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
> arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
> Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
> bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
> ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
> namedParams)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

Comment: Do you need an ampersand?  @"c:\files\ObFile.xlsx"

Comment: I added the "@" and still receive the same error. My apologies though, the C# script is actually pointing at a network share and for some reason doesn't require the "@". But the "@" is required when I point to my C drive. I'll modify my question and include the "@" (As well as my code to point to the C drive so everything is identical to my question)

Comment: I ran your code from c# and got the file.  The Culture in the exception is why I though it may be the ampersand.  How long is the Network drive filename?  May be code is failing due to long filename.  Try on local driver.  I've seen errors where a Network drive was a File Server on a Unix machine and failed.  My error was caused by zipping a file on the network drive from a window machine.  Then file wouldn't open in windows.  The Sector/Sections on the Unix machine was giving issues.  I suspect in your case it has something to do with the spaces in the filename (%20).

Comment: I am now using the local C Drive. It still isn't working. It's weird because I can point to a different file on the internet and get the file. I can run it outside of my SSIS package (Same code) and get the file I want. But it doesn't work inside SSIS's script component. Could they be using different versions of the WebClient? (I don't know C# at all and I've just been googling and guessing)

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  compare the headers in first request between working and non work.  Also check version of TLS be used.  It sound like it may be a TLS issue which is used for authentication.  The SSIS may be using an older version of TLS.  You want to use 1.2/1.3 (not 1.0/1.0).  See : https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000926174-How-to-enable-TLS-1-2-for-SSIS-2012-packages this is old so make sure you use).  Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype?view=netcore-3.1.

Comment: Yes! The script task inside SSIS is using TLS 1.0. But the one from the Console App is using 1.2!

Comment: Now we know definitely why you are failing Look at the two links I provided.  We need to add to your code the selection of TLS 1.2..

Comment: It's working now! I added this line to my script task and it resolved the issue - System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)3072;